# Fact Constellation Schema

Tags: data-warehouse

I made a fact constellation schema with 2 fact tables and 16 dimension tables with 4 common dimension tables. One of the dimension table needs to be normalized because data from data source can have variable number of rows. Can I still call it fact constellation schema having a branch in dimension table??

I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may still call it a Constellation Schema with Sliced Dimension Table.
This term is very much in Oracle Datwarehosing Book which I read around 7 years ago.

Regards,
Jit

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while just writing to help if any other people needs information about this topic. Normally fact constellation model is made up of star models where any artifical or natural hierarchy should not be present. But according to your needs you can add normalized (hierarchical) dimension tables. In this case your fact constellation made up of snowflakes instead stars.